# How to use IO Double as regular Double in Haskell

Tags: haskell, random, io, monads, do-notation

I have to following code

```
isInCircle::Double->Double->Bool
isInCircle p1 p2 = sqrt((p1*p1)+(p2*p2)) <= 1
```

and when I make a call like

```
isInCircle (random :: Double) (random :: Double)
```

I get  this error

```
* Couldn't match expected type `Double' with actual type `g0 -> (a0, g0)'
```

If I change the argument of `isInCircle` function to `IO Double` I get errors with `sqrt` and addition...

Can you help me? My code:

```
import System.Random 
main :: IO () 
main = do 
    if isInCircle (random :: Double) (random :: Double) 
    then print "True" 
    else print "False" 

isInCircle::Double->Double->Bool 
isInCircle p1 p2 = sqrt((p1*p1)+(p2*p2)) <= 1
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error you're getting with the code you've given, so I cannot help you. You must include the code that actually gets you this error. Please read up on [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: import System.Random

    main :: IO ()
    main = do
    if isInCircle (random :: Double) (random :: Double) then  print "True" else print "False"

    isInCircle::Double->Double->Bool
    isInCircle p1 p2 = sqrt((p1*p1)+(p2*p2)) <= 1

Comment: Don't post updates in comments, [edit] your question.

Comment: An `IO Double` is not a number, it's a recipe (or "action") for producing a number.

Comment: @luqui it was at -2 because before the edit, it did not provide enough information, and therefore simply could not be answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checking it out at the GHCi prompt,

```
> :i Random
class Random a where
  randomR  :: RandomGen g => (a, a) -> g -> (a, g)
  random   :: RandomGen g => g -> (a, g)
  randomRs :: RandomGen g => (a, a) -> g -> [a]
  randoms  :: RandomGen g => g -> [a]
  randomRIO :: (a, a) -> IO a
  randomIO  :: IO a
        -- Defined in `System.Random'
instance Random Integer -- Defined in `System.Random'
instance Random Int -- Defined in `System.Random'
instance Random Float -- Defined in `System.Random'
instance Random Double -- Defined in `System.Random'
instance Random Char -- Defined in `System.Random'
instance Random Bool -- Defined in `System.Random'
```

we see that instead of `random`, for `Double`, `randomIO :: IO Double` looks much more promising. If only we could somehow get at the `Double` "inside" the `IO Double` type of "value". Can we do it?

Yes we can. That's what the "bind" is for. In `do` notation it is done with `<-`:

```
import System.Random 
main :: IO () 
main = do 
    -- if isInCircle (random :: Double) (random :: Double) 
    x <- (randomIO :: IO Double)   -- thus, x :: Double
    y <- (randomIO :: IO Double)   -- thus, y :: Double
    if isInCircle x y
      then print "True"            -- print "True" :: IO ()
      else print "False"           -- (if ... ...) :: IO ()
```

The *pure* function *`isInCircle`* itself isn't changed nor does it need to be. It is still the same *pure* function operating on two pure values. But we *embed it in* a combined `IO` computation recipe, built from smaller `IO` computation recipes (including the "built-in" `randomIO` recipe) such that when the resulting combined (composed?) computation – referred to / described by the value named `main` – is performed, it will *use* the *pure* function *`inInCircle`* with the two values obtained  through the two `randomIO`s.

That's Haskell. Pure on the inside, I/O on the outside (and how else could it communicate with us if not – *by definition* – through I/O).